# Is there a way to trigger Firebase onUpdate() inside an HTTP endpoint?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my situation:

1. Client starts a login operation, has no way of knowing status or getting a response
2. Login operation has a Cloud Function callback so it saves the login status in the Realtime DB
3. Client polls a different Cloud Function to check if login status has been written in the Realtime DB to a specific node (key is a UUID)

I've been trying to write the last function with promise intervals but it feels off, and I've started wondering if I can use onUpdate() inside my HTTP endpoint?

Metacode of my idea:

```
    user = ref.child(uuid)
    user.onUpdate((update) => res.send(update.status))
```

From what I've seen in the docs/tutorials onUpdate seems something you use to deploy a function directly (since it returns a CloudFunction), so is there a way to use it as above?

If not, is there a way to do something similar in an HTTP endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make an asynchronous operation synchronous, which is not usually a great idea in Cloud Functions.

I instead would:

1. Return a unique ID/location in the database to the client in their initial call.
2. Then have the client wait until a response appears in the database location.
3. And the Cloud Function responding to the auth completion can then write to that location.

The key difference with your approach is that #2 is watching a database location, instead of polling a Cloud Function. The code this is shown in this [gist with code to wait for a value on various platforms](https://gist.github.com/puf/146fecdae240ac0e62f858f7650aa85f).

Comment: Thank you Frank. I am returning the UUID key for the login node to the client for their initial call, I don't know how to do the second part though, that's my problem. I cannot use the Firebase SDK on my Client unfortunately.

Comment: In case you're curious, this is a Game Maker client, which uses its own GML language and can't use modules/libraries/etc.

Comment: Ok I just read your gists and realised I can use .on() in my HTTP endpoint to wait for the node to be created!

Comment: I'm not sure what "my HTTP endpoint" refers to there. If it's your client-side code listening to the database endpoint, then that is indeed what I described. If it's Cloud Functions listening to a non-triggering endpoint, then that is not possible within a function

Comment: I meant an HTTP triggered cloud function, seems to me like this is working using on() on the desired Reference

Comment: The problem is that a Cloud Function can only run for a limited amount of time (at most 9 minutes iirc), so you can't reliably keep that `on` listener active.

Comment: Oh yeah I'm using the default 1-minute timeout but don't worry, I'm aware of that, I just need the listener to be on for a brief amount of time while the user logs in. I tested it today and it's working